# How would you say Season 1 Episode 1?

Tags: nombres, demande-de-mot, formatage

For describing a television episode, how would you say "Season 1 Episode 1"?

Comment: If you look at a dictionnary, you'll find easily "Season" -> "Saison" and "Episode" -> "Épisode"

Comment: @Toto I think it would be fair to say that you can't tell how the sentence is structured just from that, though. That said, the question could use some attempt on the asker's part and a note on where the uncertainty lies.

Comment: I also didn't know whether the same word that's used for weather would be used for television, because in German at least they're not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In France people say : **Saison 1 - Épisode 1**

Wikipedia article on [Saison (télévision)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saison_(t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vision)) :

> Une **saison** est un ensemble d'épisodes d'une série télévisée...

[Wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_belle_la_vie#Saisons) on the French soap *Plus belle la vie* :

> Les nombreux épisodes de *Plus belle la vie* sont officiellement répartis en saisons d'environ 260 épisodes...

And from this week's *Telerama* (French TV magazine) :
[image]